# Extracting a video from the HTML developer

Tags: html, facebook, video, download

I am trying to extract a video from Facebook that I can send to my email, however there is no link for me to download or copy from Facebook where I can send this video. I can only send it through FB messenger.

I am using the HTML Inspector/Developer tab to find the source of the video and then maybe grab & download the video this way.

I am not sure how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right Click on the video -> show video URL. 
Navigate to that URL.
Open developer tools, source code of that page.
Search for `<video ...></video>` tag.
Inside video tag, search for "`src`" attribute, copy the source of the video.
Source code of videos in facebook starts with "`blob:https://www.facebook.com/.......`"

Follow [this guide](https://superuser.com/questions/1033563/how-to-download-video-with-blob-url) on how to download `blob` url videos.

You can also use 3rd party websites or applications to download media from websites.

Please take note and check if what you are doing is legal and check facebook terms of conditions for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

Go to [www.savefrom.net/user.php](http://www.savefrom.net/user.php) and install the plugin. You will be able to download videos from many sites including facebook with 2 clicks.

If you don't want to install anything on the website I posted, enter www adress and it will download the file.